# Accidentally inverted the colour of all windows

Tags: compiz, colors

I fat fingered a short-cut in Thunderbird and now the colours of all my application windows are inverted.  I'm not sure what combination I hit (I was trying for Alt-1).  How do I get my colour scheme back to normal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens with Compiz. Typically when you press either <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> Try pressing either of these combinations to de-negatize the desktop.